# Count won't count more than one item

Tags: sql

Database and query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1db44/28

Context:

The sql statement includes two includes and selects the most serious condition for accesoires. Because of the that, the count counts only one accesoires instead of all accesoires for that product. How can i count all accesoires?

Desired result:

```
PRODUCTID   PRODUCTNAME     ACCESOIRESID    ACCESOIRESCONDITION    COUNT(A.PRODUCTID)
1           product1        2               defect                 3
2           product2        4               working                1
3           product3        6               obsolete               2
```

Thanks!

Comment: Post the full query in the question. And you likely want to `count(*)` or `count(condition_id)`, rather than `count(product_id)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added a second JOIN to the accessories table, and that seems to produce the desired result:

```
SELECT 
p.productid, 
p.productname,
a.accesoiresid,
c.conditionname,
COUNT(a2.accesoiresid)
FROM product p 
join accesoires a2 on p.productId = a2.productId
join accesoires a on p.productId = a.productId
join cond c on c.conditionid = a.accesoirescondition
  where a.accesoirescondition =
  (select min(accesoirescondition) 
     from accesoires 
    where productId = p.productId)
group by p.productid
```

In your original code, the join on `cond` includes a limitation on which `accessoryid` to JOIN on, and thus limited the results of the query.

Answer (score 2):

Well, when you're already using a subquery, why not use this:

```
(select count(*) from accesoires a where a.productId = p.productId)
```

instead of count(a.productId)?

It might also be a good idea to have a view, which returns counts of accessories per product (ie. groups the accessory table by productId and does a count). Then you could just join this view into your query and you'll get the count easily.